# subprocess has wrong pid on Windows

Tags: python, subprocess, python-3.7

main.py:

```
from subprocess import Popen
import sys

proc = Popen([sys.executable, 'sub.py'])
print('parent thinks subprocess pid is', proc.pid)
```

sub.py:

```
import os
print('subprocess thinks its pid is', os.getpid())
```

Output of `python main.py` on Linux:

```
parent thinks subprocess pid is 338
subprocess thinks its pid is 338
```

Output on Windows:

```
parent thinks subprocess pid is 17340
subprocess thinks its pid is 7308
```

Why is this?

Edit: `print(sys.executable)` gives `C:\my-venv\Scripts\python.exe`

Comment: What is `sys.executable` in your Windows test?

Comment: C:\my-venv\Scripts\python.exe (same output from main.py and sub.py)

Comment: @Chris that should go into your question itself, not a comment

Comment: This is probably a case of the subprocess launching another subprocess, though I don't know enough about the Windows Python launcher to know why that might happen.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica - I was thinking the same thing, like that there's a wrapper script of some kind involved.  Although...if it was Linux, wouldn't the two numbers be close together in that case?  I don't generally know much about Window, and maybe it doesn't work like that on Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating virtual environment on windows, it looks like that the python interpreter copied to venv's Script folder is not the actual python executable but a wrapper that executes it.

If you modify sub.py to be something like this:

```py
import os
import psutil
local_pid = os.getpid()
parent = psutil.Process(local_pid).parent()
print('subprocess thinks its pid is', os.getpid())
try:
    print("parent process of our main python is", parent.pid)
except:
    pass
```

You will see that os.getpid() will return its own pid but it has a parent when executed inside virtual env. However, when venv is deactivated, main and sub.py do report the same pid.